# How to programmatically capture / measure frame rates across browsing sessions?

Tags: scroll, google-chrome-devtools, frame-rate

I'm trying to measure client-side performance - frame rate / scrolling latency specifically - for my app. I'm wondering if anyone has found a nice way to programmatically capture this type of data? I'm trying to compare the performance across time / changes... iow, has a given change made scrolling smoother?

So far I've been doing the following:
+ start a "timeline" recording (using dev tools' "Timeline" feature / view)
+ run a simple js routine which scrolls down at a fixed rate
+ view / export / analyze Chrome's timeline data

The drawbacks to the above are that the act of scrolling the page with javascript introduces it's own performance cost and that ultimately the data I get from the timeline is... pretty thorough. Ideally, I'd be able to get at some sort of summary data - ex: average, median, 95th pct frame length / durations, and longest frame.

Anyone have any tips on this type of thing?

Comment: Have you tried to go to: chrome://flags/ and open the flag for: FPS counter - It might be great option to dev mode.

Comment: ah, neat! but i'm not sure I can do programmatically with this info?

Comment: Ya... programmatically you want something like: http://www.kaizou.org/2011/06/effectively-measuring-browser-framerate-using-css/

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically extract FPS data by opening a DevTools window on your DevTools window ("DevTools-On-DevTools"), and then running commands in the Console to extract the data from the DevTools model. This is covered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081289/1669860

Check out this unrelated answer for more help with "DevTools-On-DevTools":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198185/1669860

You might be able to achieve this with Puppeteer, also:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer