# possible to refresh chrome dev tools watch expressions manually or by code?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Taking a look at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#favorite-expression

If I don't set any breakpoints, then I have to manually click on the refresh icon in the watch expressions panel.  It would be nice if I could put in some debugging code to update the watch expressions without ever having to enter debug mode.

Something like this:

```
// some update function
setInterval(function() {
    console.refresh();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @MaheshVemuri: nah, but it may be worth filling out a feature request

Comment: @ilovett Did you ever figure out a way to do this or fill out a feature request for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### update

Check out [Live Expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch). These are similar to Watch Expressions, expect they're in the Console and they update in real-time.

### original

[wOxxOm's hack for displaying the average FPS of a Performance recording](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081289/1669860) gave me inspiration on how we could hack together a solution to this problem:

1. Open DevTools.
2. Click the **Sources** tab to open the **Sources** panel. You can navigate to other panels, but you have to open **Sources** at least once before running the code below. I'll explain why you *have* to do this later.
3. [Undock your DevTools window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=2018Q1#placement).
4. Focus your DevTools window, then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac). Another DevTools window opens up. This second window is inspecting your first DevTools window. This works because DevTools itself is just a web app.
5. In the second DevTools window, run this code in the **Console**:

   ```
   let id;
   UI.panels.sources._watchSidebarPane.widget().then(ui => {
       id = setInterval(() => {
           ui._refreshButton.element.click();
       }, 1000);
   });
   ```

We essentially just set a timer to click the "Refresh Watch Expressions" button every second.

Here's an example of the hack in action: https://youtu.be/w-3rqFhziQ4

The reason you *have* to open the **Sources** panel before running the code is because the `UI.panels` object only contains panels that you've opened. If you don't open **Sources**, the reference to `UI.panels.sources` will be undefined.