# extending google chrome devtools style inspector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to add custom functionality to **chrome devtools**?

I want to add a button in to chrome style inspecter ( green button in the picture ) .

When button is clicked, I want to show an alert with file and line number.

I read about **extending devtools** from **google documentation,** but couldn't found anything to do something like I expect.

If you think it's possible, can you tell me some starting point?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

Comment: It's not possible. You can write your own panel though, see the link above.

Answer (score 2):

DevTools tech writer here. It's not officially supported, but there are various ways you can unofficially extend DevTools:

- Write an extension, as ceejayoz mentioned in the comments.
- You might be able to [write a Snippet that automates the DevTools behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460820/possible-to-refresh-chrome-dev-tools-watch-expressions-manually-or-by-code/48198185#48198185) that you want to achieve. This workflow is quite hacky / convoluted, but powerful.
- [Run your own modified version of the source code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro/edit#heading=h.xrvlijp6kqrm). It's surprisingly easy to set up.

Comment: thanks modified version seems to be a good option for me.but one question if i modified it can i use it in chrome or i have to use chromium ?iknow they quite same but i like if i can use it in normal chrome.

Comment: hey kayce let's say i create a new tab in devtools.but then i need to list down all applied styles,overridden styles , is there a easy way to get all this in chrome api?or do i have to write my own functions for that?