# chrome (version: 86.0.4240.80) devTool, how can i get FPS info?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, frame-rate

recently, I find Chrome devTool have no `Frame mate` anymore, but `Frame Rendering Stats`, They are different panel. I can get real time FPS before, but now, it just show me how much Frame ploted and how much droped, and memory use. if I want FPS, must record preformance and analys it of write script to compute it.

so, is there any method to get real time FPS directly

Comment: See [How to get the FPS in chrome devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48079661)